# php visit counter cookie not working why?

Tags: php, cookies, counter

guys this is my code for setting up a visit counter using a php cookie but the counter won't increment after the first visit ! Means it doesn't go beyond '1'. HELP !

```
<?php

    ob_start();

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");        

    function saveCookie($name='cookie', $val='', $time=0) {
        if ($time == 0) {
            setcookie($name, $val, 0, "/");
        }     else     {
            setcookie($name, $val, time() + ($time*1000*60*60*24), "/");            
        }
    }
    function clearCookie($name='cookie') {
        setcookie($name, '', -1, "/");
    }


   $countVisit = ($_COOKIE["countVisit"]) ? $_COOKIE["countVisit"] : 0;

   if (!isset($_COOKIE["countVisit"]))
   {
      saveCookie("countVisit",1,1);
      echo "WELCOME !";
   }
  else{
        $_COOKIE["countVisit"]++;
   }

    echo "You've visited " . $countVisit . " number of times";

 // saveCookie("countVisit",$countVisit,30);

?>
```

Comment: You call your `savecookie` function if the cookie isn't set; but you never update the cookie - you increment `$_COOKIE["countVisit"]++;`, but that doesn't save the updated value in the user's cookie

Comment: ok so how do i update the cookie ?

Also, i will try save the updated value in the cookie variable.

BTW do you know what is the reference to the actual cookie , i mean what the name of the variable/name of the cookie through which i handle it ?? I am a beginner to all such kind of stuff .

Comment: The function `saveCookie` saves the cookie; you need to call it when you want to update the value